# Keep getting name error name "getName" not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying create a program that sets the users pet name, species, and age, but then gets all of the results returned and output in the end.

What can I do to fix the name error of this code?

```
class Pet :

    def main() :
        print(getName())
        print(getSpecies())
        print(getAge())

    def getName(self) :
        name = str(input("What is your pets name: "))
        return name

    def getSpecies(self) :
        species = str(input("What is your pets species: "))
        return species

    def getAge(self) :
        age = int(input("Please type in your age: "))
        return print(age)

    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access instance variables and functions from within a class you need to use `self`

```
class Pet :

    def main(self) :
        print(self.getName())
        print(self.getSpecies())
        print(self.getAge())

    def getName(self) :
        name = str(input("What is your pets name: "))
        return name

    def getSpecies(self) :
        species = str(input("What is your pets species: "))
        return species

    def getAge(self) :
        age = int(input("Please type in your age: "))
        return print(age)

myPet = Pet()
myPet.main()
```

Comment: This leads me to get "self is not defined." Am I supposed to set all the arguments to self and add a "self." in front of the appropriate variables?

Comment: main needs the argument self as well

Comment: If you call main() in the scope of the class you need to do self.main()

Comment: When I add the self argument to main() it still gives me a "self is not defined" error.

Comment: Did you do `.main()`

Comment: This is correct now. My indention was off for the last two lines.